# When do I dealloc an object?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios4, dealloc

In one of my functions, I have a while loop with a certain case where it may need to temporarily create an object.  My code looks like this:

```
while(c < end){
    if(specialCase){
        Object *myObject = [Object alloc];
        //do stuff with myObject
        //I tried [myObject dealloc] here, but it crashed when this method was called.
    }
    c++;
}
```

The code works fine as is but I am worried about memory leaks.  I would like to know if and how I should dealloc myObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You NEVER call Dealloc directly.

you call Release and when retain count reaches 0 dealloc will be called on object.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried calling release before dealloc at one point and got a bad access error.  I guess now I know why.

Answer (score 1):

you should not call `dealloc` method **directly**, Calling  `release` on the object which are either `alloced` or `retain` will call `dealloc` implicity ,if the **retain count** for that **object** meet with condition put by **iOS system** (**Usually** if the **retain count** is *ZERO* for the object).

Read the apple documentation of `dealloc` method in [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and also go through the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) for objective-C

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while(c < end){
if(specialCase){
Object *myObject = [[Object alloc] autorelease];
    //do stuff with myObject
    //I tried [myObject dealloc] here, but it crashed when this method was called.
}
c++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try using a Smart Pointer.
This should take care of garbage collection and any exception handling. Also, Boost libraries can be ported for ios.